# Is it true that $\sqrt{ab}\le \frac{a-b}{\ln a - \ln b}$ for any $a\neq b>0$?

Tags: functions, inequality, real-numbers

- Is it true that $\sqrt{ab}\le \frac{a-b}{\ln a - \ln b}$ for any $a\neq b>0$?

If so, any thoughts on how to prove this?

Comment: At the very least, it indeed holds in the limit as $b \to a$

Comment: Duplicate of [Proof of the following inequality $ \frac{x - y}{\log x - \log y} > \sqrt{xy} $, $x>y$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/577235)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion is true.  When $a>b>0$, it follows by taking $x:=\frac ab$  in [the inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3682916/215011)
$$ \log x\le \sqrt x - \frac1{\sqrt x}\qquad\text{for all $x\ge 1$}
$$
For $b>a$, just flip the roles of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

The logs only make sense if $a,b>0$. Let $a=e^{B+h},b=e^B$; without loss of generality $h>0$, i.e. $a>b$. Then
$$
\frac{a-b}{\ln a-\ln b} = \frac{e^{B+h}-e^B}{h};
$$you will recognize this as the slope of the secant line of $e^x$ at the points $x=B,x=B+h$. On the other hand,
$$
\sqrt{ab}= \sqrt{e^{B+h}e^B} = e^{B+h/2}
$$Divide by $e^B$ and substitute $h\to 2h$:
$$
e^{h/2} \leq \frac{e^h-1}{h}
$$
$$
2he^{h} \leq {e^{2h}-1}
$$This last inequality is true by Bernoulli's inequality: we have equality at $h=0$ and taking derivatives we have
$$
2e^h(1+h) \leq 2 e^{2h};\qquad 1+h \leq e^h
$$